# Should redux only be used to re-render child components?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
    export default class ParentRenderer extends React.Component {  
      // constructor with method bindings goes here

       changeMapping(e) {
            mapping.put(props.data,e.target.value);//unclear on how to declare mappings

       }

      renderChild(props) {// props passed by Parent
            <Child onChange = {(e) => this.changeMapping(e,props)} />
       } 

     sendMappings() {
        makeRestCall(mappings);//makeRestCall is imported and makes a post call to specified url
       // pass response to ParentRenderer's parent

    }

      render() {
         data = []; //each object represents data for the first column of each row
         return(
          <div>
             <Parent
                  data = {data} onRender = {this.renderChild}
             />
             <button onClick = {this.sendMappings}>Next</button>
          </div>
         );
       }
    }
```

`Parent` Component is like a table and renders each row with `Child` component. There are no ids given to each child that is rendered. A value is entered by end user to each `Child` Component. The data I've declared in render makes the first column. The second column has `Child` in each row. I want a mapping of the data in the first column to the data entered by the user. If n `Child` components are rendered I want to send these n mappings to the backend via a POST call upon the `Next` button click..`props` are sent to `renderChild` by `Parent` and it gives me access to the data in the first column for that row.

How should I store the `mappings` variable. It is changed by independent children.Can I use `react-redux` to store these mappings variable although no state change is triggered and children don't need to be re-rendered? Or can I make it a global variable? I read in the React docs that Context is experimental, so I chose not to use that.

Comment: Context is no longer experimental in 16.3 [see](https://medium.com/dailyjs/reacts-%EF%B8%8F-new-context-api-70c9fe01596b)

Comment: I have to use 15.6.2